# JsonEncode returns empty string in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to encode an Array into Json. I tried with a complex one and the result was empty. So I tried with a very simple array and the result was the same:

```
$result=Array("pippo", "pluto");
print_r($result);
json_encode($result);
```

The print_r correctly prints the array, but json_encode returns nothing.
What may be the problem?

Comment: You need to print it `echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: Yes, I found out myself. That is not so much evident from the samples that the function does not print its own output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below

```
<?php
    $result=Array("pippo", "pluto");
    print_r($result);
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Or Refer URL https://eval.in/631616

Answer (score 0):

Output seems to be ok when running your code.

```
string(17) "["pippo","pluto"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course json_encode returns its encoding and does not print it. So it is needed to echo it.